# Conditional Probability on Cards of the Same Suit

Tags: probability, combinations

A normal deck of 52 playing cards is well shuffled and then 4 cards are dealt to Ann and 4 cards ar dealt to Bob. Ann looks at her c that all 4 of them are from the same suit, that suit being hearts. She is interested in the probability that Bob also has 4 cards that belong to a single suit, allowing for her knowledge of the  cards she holds.

Please correct my answer if it is incorrect: 
$$\text{Probability}=P(\text{Bob has all hearts} |\text{Ann has all hearts})+P(\text{Bob has all clubs/spades/diamonds}|\text{Ann has all hearts})$$

$$=\frac{\binom{9}{4}}{\binom{48}{4}}+\frac{\binom{3}{1}\times\binom{13}{4}}{\binom{48}{4}}$$

$$=\frac{757}{64860}$$

I am aware that this is a conditional probability, but I was unsure how to apply Bayes' Theorem in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A)$ = P(Anne has all hearts) =$$\frac{ ^{13}C_4}{^{52}C_4}$$
$P(B)$ = P(Bod has same suite) =$$\frac{^{13}C_4\cdot ^3C_1+^9C_4}{^{52}C_4}$$

> Using:
>   $$P(B\mid A)=\frac{P( A ∩ B)}{P(A)}$$

P(A ∩ B)=$$\frac{(^{13}C_4 \cdot 3+ ^{9}C_4)\cdot ^{13}C_4}{^{52}C_8}$$

You get:  $$P(B\mid A)=(\frac {(^{13}C_4 \cdot 3+ ^{9}C_4)\cdot ^{13}C_4}{^{52}C_8 })\cdot(\frac{^{52}C_4}{^{13}C_4})$$

Comment: To obtain $P(B \mid A)$, type `$P(B \mid A)$`.  Also, check your last line.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks for that, but whats wrong in last line?

Comment: Your probability is greater than $1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig An additional C(4,1) in denominator, i.e. in P(A)?

Comment: After reading your answer more carefully, I realized that what you should have done is divided the probability that Ann has all hearts and Bob has all cards of the same suit by the probability that Ann has all hearts.  What you did is divide the probability that Bob has all cards of the same suit by the probability that Ann has all hearts.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig so numerator must be: $$(C(13,4)*3+C(9,4))*C(13,4)*C(4,1)$$?

Comment: Both the numerator and denominator must be probabilities.  Also, I do not understand why you have the factor $\binom{4}{1}$.  The number of ways Ann can receive four hearts and Bob can receive four cards of the same suit is $$\binom{13}{4}\left[\binom{3}{1}\binom{13}{4} + \binom{9}{4}\right]$$  as you stated in your answer.  However, your denominator for $\Pr(A \cap B)$ is incorrect.  How many cards are being selected?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Yeah...$C(52,8)$. And i later added $C(4,1)$ to select a suite-heart; but we dont need to it seems...

Comment: i complicated a simple question... ;-\

Comment: It is not that simple.  Had it been simple, you would have had an easier time solving it and I would have had an easier time detecting where you made an error (had you made one).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig edited...plz have a look...

Comment: @N.F.Taussig And Thanks, for taking me through this. Got to learn something new.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by P(B)? (Even though you don't end up using this for the question). It looks like you have assumed that Ann already has 5 hearts. But then why would it be 52C4 in the denominator?)

Answer (score 0):

Letting $X$ be the event where Bob has $4$ cards of the same suit and letting $H$ be the event where Ann has four hearts.

$$P(X|H)=\frac{P(X\cap H)}{P(H)}$$

where

$$P(H)=\frac{\binom{13}{4}}{\binom{52}{4}}$$

and

$$P(X \cap H)=\frac{\binom{13}{4}\times \left(\binom{3}{1}\times\binom{13}{4}+\binom{9}{4} \right)}{\binom{52}{4}\times\binom{48}{4}}$$

Substituing into the conditional probability gets the result that I originally posted in my solution.